# KINECT: How to identify when the user is walking up or down using Kinect?

Tags: c#, kinect

I just need to create a console program where it output a string where identify is the person is walking up or down?

Do you know an example using this for KINECT?

I'm a rather new using the SDK.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Up or down what? Stairs? A ramp?

Answer (score 7):

check my blog to get positions of skeleton joints ( https://naokinect.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/kinectcomment-recuperer-les-coordonnees-des-joints-dun-squelette/ )

1 -> save the initial position of the person .Take the position from the footright when the user is ready ( for this, i ask to the user to put his right hand in the front of his head in a function) for example :

function "checkuserisready":

```
if(_coord[4] != null && _coord[0] != null && _coord[8] != null){
if (_coord[4].X <= _coord[8].X + 0.1 && _coord[4].X >= _coord[8].X - 0.1 
&& _coord[4].Y <= _coord[8].Y+0.1 && _coord[4].Y >= _coord[8].Y-0.1)
{
_initPos = _coord[9];
```

2 -> create virtual lines in "checkuserisready"(which will virtually be in the front and back of the user) :

```
float _anteriorSafeLine = (float)_initPos.Z - 0.2f;
float _posteriorSafeLine = (float)_initPos.Z + 0.2f;
```

3 -> check if the user exceeds the line in a loop

```
if ((_anteriorControlLine <= _coord[9].Z) && (_coord[9].Z <= _anteriorSafeLine)){

//move forward

}
```

same thing with posteriorsafeline to the move backward

EDIT (for the comment below):

each _coord is a skeleton joint. Its just a Vector3 Array.

e.g. :

```
_coord[0] = new Vector3(joint.Position.X,joint.Position.Y,joint.Position.Z);

//0 -> HandLeft
//1 -> ElbowLeft
//2 -> ShoulderLeft
//3 -> hipLeft
//4 -> HandRight
//5 -> ElbowRight
//6 -> ShoulderRight
//7 -> hipRight
//8 -> Head
//9 -> FootRight
```

Comment: one doubt, what are the numbers of the function checkuserisready? are they joints of the body? which please, I'm getting confusing those numbers